# Why does WPF detect another folder of the same name of my project

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to include the namespace in my mainwindow.xaml but the system says: The name "ImportView" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:LuhodAngelo.Views" but when I use xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LuhodAngelo.LuhodAngelo.ViewModels" it worked as expected. I don't know why does it happen in my program.

I already tried transfering my project in another drive like what instructed in another question. I already tried clean and rebuild or restart visual studio.
I already tried doing it in another project but still it show the same

[When I checked my projects full path and the name of my project is double](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o83qO.png)

Comment: If in your code, that works now, you remove the 'vm' namespace, does it still work? Or it fails?

Comment: @LupuSilviu it gives an error. The namespace prefix "vm" is not defined

Comment: This is because the datacontext you are using is from 'vm'. That is why the build fails now. Your view is in the right namespace but you need both to be able to build the MainWindow view.

Comment: I got your point but what I am confused about is why in c# the namespace can be like this xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LuhodAngelo.ViewModels" while in vb.net it will be like this xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LuhodAngelo.LuhodAngelo.ViewModels"

Comment: it can't be the case. it seems to me that `ImportView` is messed up somehow. wrong namespace, wrong xaml class tag, version mismatch, and outdated external reference are my 4 first guesses

Comment: BTW folder path has **absolutely** nothing to do with namespace. you have to check the actual namespace value instead of folder path

Comment: I already check the actual namespace. Please see example in this link. The namespace used is type twice [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/MVVM-Code-Sample-using-the-171c8f26/sourcecode?fileId=138466&pathId=1975089982)